# Deletion of Read only files on a windows machine running a python script

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have some files on a windows machine(directory d:/test/temp/). For some of the files i have read only permission. For the deletion of the files/folder in the above directory I use a python scripts which recursively iterates over the directory and deletes every file in it.

Following is the snippet of code used for the deletion:

```
for entry in  listdir(dest_folder):  
    if isfile(join(dest_folder,entry)) and  basename(filename) != entry:  
       remove(join(dest_folder,entry))
```

I use a user named: **tectt** which has all permissions to delete the file.

When I logged into the windows machine with that user I was able to delete the read only files manually. But when I try to delete the read only files through python scripts, I was unable to delete the files.

An error was thrown saying: **[Error 5] Access is denied**

I'm new to python scripting. Can some please help me out:
1. To delete these read only files with scripts?
2. Am i missing any things, if so, what would have been them?

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829043/how-to-remove-read-only-attrib-directory-with-python-in-windows). Just try to use the search function.

```
import os, stat
os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
os.unlink(path)
```

[How to remove read-only attrib directory with Python in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829043/how-to-remove-read-only-attrib-directory-with-python-in-windows)